# Building a modular library in C

Tags: c, modularization

I have built a library in C but at this moment it is huge and there many functions for different proposes, like: files manipulation, mathematical functions and etc.

What I would like to do is split this library for all the different proposes, but if the user wants to use all could call it at once (idk if it is possible).

My library is called feg_tools. So at the moment to use it I do:

```
#include "feg_tools.h"
```

I would like something that I call only what I need like:

```
#include "feg_tools/mathematics_functions.h"
#include "feg_tools/file_manipulation.h"
```

or if I need everything:

```
#include "feg_tools"
```

I also don't know how to build the Makefile like that.

Comment: The header files don't dictate what code gets linked in. Just include everything and let the compiler sort it out unless that's a severe performance drag. Chunking out a shared library into a bunch of modules makes for needless complexity.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create a folder named *feg_tools*, and put there all of yours library's `.h` (mathematics_functions.h,file_manipulation.h,...), then you can use them as you say in your question.

For include the hole library you'll need a header with all the `#include` directives of your library, that could be,

*feg_tools.h*

```
#include "feg_tools/mathematics_functions.h"
#include "feg_tools/file_manipulation.h"
...
```

Here the feg_tools.h was outside of the *feg_tools* folder.

I don't know if you do it, bot you should also in each `.h` file insert the content insede an `#ifdef` directive, as following:

```
#ifdef FEG_TOOLS_XXX
//put here the content 
#endif //FEG_TOOLS_XXX
```

That is for avoid circular dependencies of header files.